# How to predict an outcome based on a multi-variable linear regression model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, multiple-regression, predictive-models

I should start by saying that I'm really new to machine learning so please bear with me if I may not understand some simple concepts.
I have a small dataset of people with diabetes, something like this:

```
Age  Mbi   Glucose
50   70     148
34   60     100

..etc
```

And I tried to apply linear regression on `R` with `lm()` function and assigned it to a variable called MyModel so I can predict **Age** having **Mbi** and **Glucose** as **independent variables**.
And I get different plots when use the `show()`.
But what I cannot do (even after searching for some hours) is to use that model for a real case scenario, for example to predict the age if the level of *glucose is 145* and *mbi is 65*.
Should I use a specific function for this?

Comment: See the help page of predict.lm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fit <- lm(Y~X, data=train)

predictions <- predict(fit,newdata=test)
```

You use the predict function to score a new data set with an existing model.

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly was i was searching for ! :)